# Simple JSON read in C# (was using Java - need it in .NET)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

In Java my json code is:

```
String result = ....some json string
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
bearerToken = jObject.getString("access_token");
```

That's it!

I am trying to use newtonsoft in a C# program to do the same thing without setting up an object to deserialize to.
Thanks

Comment: Okay, so "What have you tried, and how doesn't it work?" It's effectively the same when not using POCO/dynamic deserialization methods.

Comment: my suggestion would be to set a breakpoint on that 3rd line, and use your debugger to look at what jObject is and what is inside.

Comment: My suggestion would be to take a few minutes to read the introductory parts of the JSON.NET documentation. When you have a specific problem, come back here and ask a specific question.

Comment: I don't understand the issue with my question.  I have a small piece of java code above and I am looking for a .net equivalent.  this seems pretty specific to me.  Matt below seems to have answered it pretty well. I have read the JSON.NET documentation and looked over the sample code none of which provides an equivalent solution.  Currently I wam using a reader to read the whole lot and then wait for the right token to show up - which seems like the long way around ,which is why I asked this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(result);
string bearerToken = jObject.Value<string>("access_token");
```

Comment: Hi Matt - this looks perfect - which library are you using to get the JOject?  I am using (using Newtonsoft.Json;) however I have no JObject that you are using above

Comment: I found it - it's in the linq namespace, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Johnson's answer is the most specific 1-1 translation.

However, if your Json contains more than one property, in .net you have [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) which is less typing than `.Value<string>("foo");` if you have to access several values.

This will fill the dynamic variable with your json string's properties:

```
var json = "{ access_token : \"SomeValue\" }";
dynamic jsonDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, new ExpandoObject());
Console.WriteLine(jsonDto.someProp);
```